# Jhipster add new filed when sending logs to logstash

Tags: jhipster

We are using jhipster for our microservices apps and sending app logs directly to logstash server using **jhipster.logging.logstash.host** properties. All our apps and elk(jhipster console) are running as docker containers. We are planning to run multiple docker swarm stacks(dev sita sitb etc) on a single docker host. We have only one ELK server and all logs will go to this server. I would like to index the logs using environment names like stack-deva, stack-sita etc. For this, is there a way to add a new field like 'env' in jhipster properties that can be used in logstash to create indexes? for example

```
 if env == 'sita' {
       index => "sita-projectname"
   }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define several tcp listeners on different ports in `logstash.conf`.
This way you could have different indexes, your apps properties would use a different port per environment.

Comment: Just making sure I understand you correctly. so lets say i have three environments on same docker host and I defined three tcp listeners in logstash input, so each tcp input is taking logs from each environment. And in the output I use the port number to direct logs to different indexes? Is this how i do it?  And in jhipster properties the logstash port number should be changed to respective tcp listener port number?

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly. I did not do it myself so consider it as a simple suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. will try. And just curious what does jhipster use internally to send logs to logstash?

Comment: jhipster uses logstash-logback-encoder, if you need to add fields you can either modify LoggingConfiguration.java or put values into the logback MDC